# JSON sub level value c#

Tags: c#, json, facebook, facebook-oauth

I have a Facebook reply as follows:

```
dynamic response = client.Get("me", new { fields = "verified, picture" });

BELOW IS THE JSON IN 'response'
{"verified":true,    
"picture":{"data":{"url":"https://www.abc.com","is_silhouette":true}}}
```

How do I access the 'url' value in the subkey of 'picture'? Here's what I tried but it fails:

```
fbPicture = response["picture.data.url"].toString();
```

I've tried different syntax but to no avail and I've also looked around but to no avail.

Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Facebook C# SDK implements an object called JsonObject.
So the easiest would be to cast the returnvalue (in JSON) to the JsonObject.

In your case this should be something like:

```
<!-- language-all: C# -->
dynamic response = client.Get("me", new { fields = "verified, picture" });
string url = response.picture.data.url;
```

Comment: I am using the FB C# SDK. So this is probably what I'm looking for. Will try it once I get home tonight. Thanks man !

Comment: Bingo, thanks man. That did the trick. I figured it was some syntax issue 'cause I could see the JSON data, but I just didn't know the proper syntax to pull the data. Thanks again !

Answer (score 1):

I'm not entirely sure which Json library you are using, but perhaps try this:

```
fbPicture = response["picture"]["data"]["url"].ToString();
```

Comment: I tried Cedric's answer first and it worked. Just for kicks, I tried your's as well. For the record, your's works as well with or without ".ToString()" ... thanks!